# After replacing object tag with img tag UI comes blank

Tags: html, pdf, svg, iframe, mime-types

I am converting PDF files to HTML5 using IDR tool (https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter) .It has object tag which renders svg file. As referred from [SVG not showing in object tag after publishing to web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427403/svg-not-showing-in-object-tag-after-publishing-to-web) I added '.svg' mime type to the application's web.config file or IIS server. Still it didn't work. I tried replacing `object` tag with `img` tag and data property with `src` property. Then it leads to empty UI page. Also I tried with the `iframe` tag but it leads to UI distortion. Is there any other way to solve this ?

The code line is as below:

```
<div id="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><object width="935" height="1210" data="1/1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="pdf1" style="width:935px; height:1210px; background-color:white; -moz-transform:scale(1); z-index: 0;"></object></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referred from https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML I used `<embed>` tag in my code. It just works fine.